# Automatically SUM the quantity if Duplicate Value entered in same column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range A1:B10, for data entry, where A1:A10 for Item Name and B1:B10 for there Quantity.
I need the VBA for, If I entered same Item Name in Range A1:A10, they automatically SUM there Quantity in Range B1:B10, and delete the duplicate value entered?

> ```
> For Example: -
> A1 = Apple, B1 = 10
> A2 = Coconut, B2 = 5
> A3 = Banana, B3 = 8
>
> And When I will enter
> A4 = Apple, B4 = 2
> Then
> B1 Should be 12
> and A4:B4 should be clear.
> ```

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'On change of item, if Row found and add to receipt
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E10")) Is Nothing And Range("E10").Value <> Empty Then AddItem

'On Change of Price Or Qty For Added Items
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F8,F6")) Is Nothing And Range("B4").Value = False And Range("B6").Value <> Empty Then
    Dim RecptRow As Long
    RecptRow = Range("B6").Value 'Receipt Row
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F6")) Is Nothing Then Range("M" & RecptRow).Value = Target.Value 'Update Price
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F8")) Is Nothing Then Range("L" & RecptRow).Value = Target.Value 'Update Qty
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes you can do that with VBA, look up the `worksheet change` event.

Comment: Sir, If possible, can you provide the Complete VBA Code for that?

Thank You In Advance...

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, its a Q&A site that has fairly strict rules and moderation. Here is [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this site. Effort into solving the issue and specifically what you are struggling with is required.

Comment: keep all rows and use a pivot table?

Comment: Sir if this possible with vba than please provide the VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' or whatever other method used to determine lastrow

For Each xTarget In Target
 If xTarget.Row = lastRow And xTarget.Column = 2 Then 'if B4 was changed
     Call addIt(item:=Cells(xTarget.Row, xTarget.Column - 1), xTarget:=xTarget) ' passing in just xTarget so can use the value and the row

 
End If

Next xTarget
End Sub

Sub addIt(item, xTarget)

For x = 1 To xTarget.Row - 1 ' minus one because obviously dont wanna check the value you just now entered
  If LCase(Trim(Cells(x, "A"))) = LCase(Trim(item)) Then ' lcase and trim to allow for whitespaces and case insensitivity
      Cells(x, "B") = Cells(x, "B") + xTarget.value
    
    'now will blank out if added to upper item
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Cells(xTarget.Row, xTarget.Column) = "" 'b lr
      Cells(xTarget.Row, xTarget.Column - 1) = "" 'a lr
      Cells(xTarget.Row, xTarget.Column - 1).Activate 'a lr.activate

      Application.EnableEvents = True

      Exit Sub 'stop looping and get out

End If
Next x

End Sub
```

I use a for each xTarget in Target just in case you ever modify more than cell at a time(deleting something) so it wont throw an error

If lastrow column b was changed then it fires off the addIt sub
then it disables events so we don't get into an infinite loop if we then set lastrow column b and a  to blank.

If you have more questions about this answer please add a comment! And mark as answered if this answers your question

Comment: You are Genius Mr. Josh Pachner. But I don't need only for one range("B4"). I want this for all cell in range("B1:B10"). Like if A1:A5 are unique data then ok but when I write a duplicate data from above unique value After A5, it should be added to upper value. not only fora single cell A4 or B4. Your code is working perfectly, but only for A4 to B4.

Comment: Hey sumit, that's because of the if statement xtarget.row = 4 and xtarget.column = 2 then.... You would need to dynamically have that of statement be changing. Possibly by checking to see if it's the last row first

Comment: Hey Sumit, i just made the changes that allow for it to grow. By finding last row and then checking to see if the last row was the cell that was changed this then fires off the addIt sub. If the value is found then it will add it and then blank out the cell that was added. If not found then it will leave the entered item value pair alone

Comment: Unbelievable, unimaginable, you have given the world a unique VBA code. Thank You Very Very Much Sir. Hats Off.

Comment: Thanks Kumar, accept my answer as the answer please